# How to find longest increasing sequence starting at each position within the array in O(n log n) time,

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, sequence, dynamic-programming

How could we find longest increasing sub-sequence starting at each position of the array in     O(n log n) time, I have seen techniques to find longest increasing sequence ending at each position of the array but I am unable to find the other way round.

e.g.
for the sequence " 3 2 4 4 3 2 3 "
output must be   " 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 "

Comment: Should the first output not be 1?

Comment: @leppie sorry it should be sub-sequence, so 3,4 is a valid subsequence

Comment: @quasiverse could you please elaborate how to do it backwards?

Comment: Reverse the array; find LIS ending at each position (this can be done in O(n) time); reverse the results.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Are you sure it can be done in O(n) time? If he were asking about contiguous subsequences, that would be trivial, but he needs general LIS, which is O(n log n) if memory serves.

Comment: @JensRoland: You're right -- LIS is O(nlog n).  Must have been thinking of something else!

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick and dirty JavaScript implementation (note: it is O(n^2)):

```
function lis(a) {
    var tmpArr = Array(),
        result = Array(),
        i = a.length;

    while (i--) {
        var theValue = a[i],
            longestFound = tmpArr[theValue] || 1;

        for (var j=theValue+1; j<tmpArr.length; j++) {
            if (tmpArr[j] >= longestFound) {
                longestFound = tmpArr[j]+1;
            }
        }
        result[i] = tmpArr[theValue] = longestFound;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Bwj9s/1/

We run through the array right-to-left, keeping previous calculations in a separate temporary array for subsequent lookups.

The `tmpArray` contains the previously found subsequences beginning with any given value, so `tmpArray[n]` will represent the longest subsequence found (to the right of the current position) beginning with the value `n`.

The loop goes like this: For every index, we look up the value (and all higher values) in our `tmpArray` to see if we already found a subsequence which the value could be prepended to. If we find one, we simply add 1 to that length, update the `tmpArray` for the value, and move to the next index. If we don't find a working (higher) subsequence, we set the `tmpArray` for the value to 1 and move on.

---

In order to make it O(n log n) we observe that the `tmpArray` will always be a decreasing array -- it can and should use a binary search rather than a partial loop.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I didn't read the post completely, sorry. I thought you needed the longest increasing sub-sequence for all sequence. Re-edited the code to make it work.

I think it is possible to do it in linear time, actually. Consider this code:

```
int a[10] = {4, 2, 6, 10, 5, 3, 7, 5, 4, 10};
int maxLength[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // array of zeros
int n = 10; // size of the array;

int b = 0;


while (b != n) {
  int e = b;     
  while (++e < n && a[b] < a[e]) {} //while the sequence is increasing, ++e
  while (b != e) { maxLength[b++] = e-b-1; }
}
```

Comment: That will find the longest increasing sub*string* in linear time. A sub*sequence* is allowed to skip out any number of elements, making it a tougher problem. E.g. `2 3 4 10` is a subsequence of your example sequence. (Yes, the terminology is a bit confusing...)